# Storing the data from two rows in array jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, store

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="center">
            <td></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
            <td width="35"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                Numar:
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="20%">
                Pierderi:
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="unit-item hidden">
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this table, that I cannot modify, how can I store the numbers from those two rows into two arrays with jQuery ?

Comment: `$('td .unit-item hidden').each(function(){alert($(this).html());});` I tried just to alert at first, but it doesnt alert anything. And yes, i have jquery loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if you want the numbers from the last two rows in a three row table -

```
var arrone = [];
var arrtwo = [];

$("table tr").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('td.unit-item').each(function() {
        i == 1 ? arrone.push($.trim($(this).text())) : arrtwo.push($.trim($(this).text()));
    })
})

console.log(arrone.join(','));
console.log(arrtwo.join(','));
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/qRSDM/

Here's a slightly terser example using `map` -

```
var arrone = $("table tr:nth-child(2)").find('td.unit-item').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
});

var arrtwo = $("table tr:nth-child(3)").find('td.unit-item').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
});

console.log(arrone.get().join(','));
console.log(arrtwo.get().join(','));
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/XjXaj/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new Array();
$("td .unit-item").each(function(){
    array.push($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but i managed to do it quite easier.


var array = new Array();
$("#attack_info_def td").each(function(){ if ($(this).attr('class') == 'unit-item') array.push($(this).html()); });                  this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .map function. I'm on a mobile device right now so can't test it, but something like the below should work:

`var result = jQuery("table tr").map(function () {return jQuery(this).find("td").map(function () { return jQuery(this).text(); }) });`

Answer (score 0):

Posting a more general solution that will work for an arbitrary number of rows.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NdbUh/)

```
var bArray = [];
$('tr').has('td.unit-item').each(function() {
    bArray.push($(this).find('td.unit-item').map(function() {
        return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
    }).get());
});
for(var i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(bArray[i]);
}
```